# How can i use multiple selects in ACCESS vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

How can i use multiple selects in ACCESS?

I want to do something like that:

```
New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Alunosescola", con) and ("SELECT * FROM Stock where Quantidade > 0", con)
```

But i dont know how i can do that in ACCESs.

Thank you

Comment: Have you any juncture/Link  between "Alunosescola" and "Stock " ?

Comment: have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

do you mean to Join the selects into one result?:-

[MS Access Select Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: To quote the help "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Answer (score 1):

You can write :

```
New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Alunosescola LEFT JOIN Stock ON Alunosescola.AlunosescolaID = Stock.StockID where Stock.Quantidade > 0 ", con)
```